# Filtering XML based on multiple params - Flex

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to filter an XML based on multiple parameters that I have as an input.

I am trying to identify the parent nodes which have the matching records so that I can filter them out and process.

```
<A>
    <B1>
        <C1>
            <D1>111</D1>
            <E1>111</E1>
            <F1>
                <G1>111</G1>
                <H1>
                    <I1>111</I1>
                    <J1>111</J1>
                </H1>
            </F1>
        </C1>
    </B1>
    <B1>
        <C1>
            <D1>222</D1>
            <E1>333</E1>
            <F1>
                <G1>222</G1>
                <H1>
                    <I1>222</I1>
                    <J1>222</J1>
                </H1>
            </F1>
        </C1>
    </B1>
    <B1>
        <C1>
            <D1>333</D1>
            <E1>333</E1>
            <F1>
                <G1>333</G1>
                <H1>
                    <I1>333</I1>
                    <J1>333</J1>
                </H1>
            </F1>
        </C1>
    </B1>
</A>
```

Lets say I need to match for the node D1 and E1 and I1, but if there is a 'AND' match from all the parameters, I need to have the node right from `<B1>` for the result.

```
<B1>
    <C1>
        <D1>222</D1>
        <E1>333</E1>
        <F1>
            <G1>222</G1>
            <H1>
                <I1>222</I1>
                <J1>222</J1>
            </H1>
        </F1>
    </C1>
</B1>
```

I am trying usng the below combination to get the data:

```
xml..*.((hasOwnProperty("D1") && D1 == "222")&&hasOwnProperty("E1") && D1 == "333"))
```

But think there is some gap. Can someone fill in and tell me where am I going wrong or is there a better approach to filter an XML?
Also, is there something which the filterFunction (collections) can help out with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `..` operator, or call its equvalent`descendants()` to get an XMLList of all sub nodes that match your criteria, regardless of where they are in the hierarchy.  Then, using `xml.( criteria )`, select only the nodes that also match the expression within the parentheses:

```
var result:XMLList = xml..B1.(
   ( descendants ("D1") == "222" ) && 
   ( descendants ("E1") == "333" ) && 
   ( descendants ("I1").length() > 0 )  // or any other expression
   );
```

Comment: I am trying to create the Query part dynamically so that params and the keys take over for building the criteria part. Just to show:

`var q1:String = "descendants (\"E1" ) == \"111\" )";`//dynamic query building, this is just for demo.

`Alert.show("Query>>"+q1.toString()); //Output: descendants ("E1" ) == "111"`
    
`var r2:XMLList = xmlData..*.(descendants ("E1" ) == "111");//Gives correct answer`


`var r1:XMLList = xmlData..*.(q1.toString());// Gives weird response, doesn't filter out anything.`

**Is something missing here or is this the wrong approach for it.**

Comment: The expression inside the parentheses should not be a string.  But apart from that: You should not ask questions in comments, even as a follow-up - post a new question instead! :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the StackTip:)
Followup question posted.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185413/dynamic-xml-filtering-based-on-params