# Dynamic XML filtering based on params

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Follow up question on [Filtering XML based on multiple params - Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183734/filtering-xml-based-on-multiple-params-flex).

I was trying to create the Query part dynamically so that params and the keys take over for building the criteria part. Just to show:

```
 //building a dynamic query like this 
var q1:String = "descendants (\"E1" ) == \"111\" )"; 
Alert.show("Query>>"+q1.toString());     // Output: descendants ("E1" ) == "111"

var r2:XMLList = xmlData..*.(descendants ("E1" ) == "111"); //returns correct result 
var r1:XMLList = xmlData..*.(q1.toString());  // weird response, 
                                              // doesn't filter out anything
```

A comment here [Filtering XML based on multiple params - Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183734/filtering-xml-based-on-multiple-params-flex#comment11557459_9184132) says that the expression inside the parentheses should not be a string. Agreed.

So, is there any other approach to filter out multiple parameters in XML than to use the 
`descendants()`, which currently is not working out because we are building the search query dynamically, based on the params searched?

Any pointers/ideas would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing the filtering in a loop?

```
var filters : Array = [ { key : "E1", value : "333" }, { key : "D1", value : "333" } ];

var searchItem : XMLList = xmlData.*;
for each (var filter:Object in filters)
    searchItem = searchItem.( descendants ( filter.key ) == filter.value);

trace (searchItem);
```

Comment: Yes, that's understood. But depending on the input params it may be one or more, I am trying to create the dynamic query having one or more params to be searched as descendants.

Comment: I've changed my answer.  Note that xmlData.* returns the children, not all descendants, of the root node - otherwise the method could return the same subtrees in smaller chunks over and over again.

Comment: OK, this would work. We are iterating the same list over different descendants. Great.